# Are student research assistants included in papers as contributor for their work?

Tags: publications, citations, research-undergraduate

I was a B.Sc. student research assistant for programming in a Neuroscience Lab in Germany. My Job was to code experiments, manage the data gathered and to write/modify the scripts to evalute these datasets. I was employed for the work of a PhD. student but I have simply became the programmer guy of the whole Lab and made diverse scripts and experiments for many people in the Lab. People were really happy with my work and everything was working fine.

I quitted the job because my PhD. advisor refused to write me as a contributor even though I worked there for 18 months. Also I wasn't learning new stuff, so I wanted to get into a new Lab, that can challenge me to learn new things. I told them, that I quit because I want to find a new job which fits my future working field better. We have currently no problems with my advisor or any other person in the Lab.

But after I quit, I asked for a Recommendation Letter from my advisor, with the expectation that he will ask Professor to write it. But instead he sent me an e-mail telling that he will write it himself.

My concern is, after spending 18 months in a Lab with a work on around 15 different projects, 5 different papers and for 10 people, I get no contribution and get only a recommendation letter from a PhD. student, which has no weight in Academia. For the new Institutes, this may look like I was a bad student research assistant, who was almost useless.

My question is am I right with my concerns? Do I have to contact Prof. for my contributions and a Recommendation Letter without telling it to my advisor? I have simply no experience in this field, but I want do a PhD. degree in future and I am worried that, this kind of thing might be a waste of time for me or even worse, a bad impact for my future.

Thank You!

Comment: I think you are using the word citation incorrectly. What I think you mean is formal acknowledgement. Papers get cited, and through them, their authors. But papers can contain acknowledgements for non-author contributors.

Comment: It's confusing to under stand the "bottom line" of what you're asking.

Comment: @Buffy thank you for pointing that out, I edited it now, what I meant was contribution.

Comment: @6005 I edited it now, sorry for selecting wrong word. My bottom line is, after working for 18 months in a lab, I will get no contributions for my work in projects and I only get a recommendation letter from a PhD. student. I think I deserve at least a good recommendation letter from Prof. after my work. Am I expecting too much? I

Comment: Since you contributed to multiple projects, that fact should be stated in your letters of recommendation. If one letter writer has enough information to make your multiple contributions clear, that's fine, but if not then you may want to get several letters about your contributions to several projects --- not necessarily a letter for every project, but enough so that readers will get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standards for who is a co-author differ by field, and maybe by location. In some fields everyone who has any contribution at all gets listed as a co-author. In others only one person or the main contributors to the actual concepts presented. So, it is impossible to judge in your case without knowing more about the specific academic culture.

But as a minimum you should probably be acknowledged in some statement within the paper itself.

I'm guessing that in your case the professor isn't being mean or unethical, but the field is just such that "authorship" has a specific meaning that may not apply to you. If you work pretty much under the direction of someone else, then you may not actually "deserve" co-authorship.

I'll note, however, that there are papers in some fields, such as high energy physics, in which the list of authors is longer than the paper itself.

But note that this is a very controversial subject.

The other issue of who writes your letter of recommendation is separate. In general if you have had little contact with the professor then they know little of your work and can hardly make a prediction about your future success. The PhD student might actually be better, provided that the letter is properly written. As a minimum, the professor should review and approve the letter (IMO). It is also possible that this is field dependent and thus it may be that whoever reads your LoR will be in the same field and understand the conventions. Math might be quite different from biochemistry, for example.

---

To respond to your comment, I suggest that if there is a dispute among lab members about whether you should be a co-author, that you let them resolve it on your behalf. If the other PhD student carries the ball for you it is more likely to be successful than if you do it alone.

Comment: The things is, I only spoke to my own advisor about co-authoring. My professor doesn't know about it. Also another PhD. student mentioned, that I have to be included as a co-author in papers for my great work. But I thought it might be mean to tell Professor that my advisor refused me as a co-author and I deserve it.

Comment: And about the recommendation letter, I am a computer engineering student and you are a CS Prof. as I see in your profile. My advisor(PhD.) sent me a recommendation letter ,which he prepared for another intern student, so I can write my own and he can edit it. There was only his name at the end of it. So I think he will make the same for me by not mentioning Prof. in the letter. What would you think about an application with a  recommendation letter, written only from a PhD. student after 18 months of work?Should I take it? I can't find a way to tell "I want a letter from Prof., not from you"

Comment: Just opinion, but you should take it. A letter from both may be the best outcome. But you probably have other suitable letter writers as well.

Comment: Maybe I can ask him to include Professor's name in the letter too. You mean the other PhD. students from the lab as letter writers?

Comment: Actually no, professors from other courses.